# Adding class level permission to methods

Tags: python, class, interface

So I have a class name Player defined like below:

```
class Player:

    def insert(score):
      # implementation of score insert

    def retrieve(player_id)
      # implementation of retrieval
```

Now, I want to modify the insert and retrieve functions so that a username is passed and only if username has admin role I should be able to insert or retrieve (I have a user class). So I modified the methods like below:

```
def insert(score, username):
    u = UserModel()
    if not u.is_admin_user(username):
        print('User does not have access to retrieve data')
        return False
    #implementation of score insert
```

This works fine, however I have various other models, with many different methods who all need this restriction and I would need to add this snippet everywhere. So is there something cool in Python OOPS using which I can use? I am talking in terms of interface or decorator or something like that. I am not very strong with OOPS...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you can make a decorator that does the verification, and decorate the functions accordingly

Comment: You should not mix responsibilities within one class. You should look up the SOLID design principles.

Comment: I know that @quamrana I just dont know how to implement it in python. I am more of a front end designer...

Comment: Its the same as with any OOP language.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do without too much of a redesign is a simple function definition for your check.

```
def check_permissions(username):
    u = UserModel()
    if not u.is_admin_user(username):
        raise PermissionError('User does not have access to retrieve data')

class Player:
    def insert(self, score, username):
        check_permissions(username)
        # implementation of score insert
        
    def retrieve(self, player_id, username):
        check_permissions(username)
        # implementation of retrieval
```

This way you don't need to repeat whole authentication logic in every place you want to add the check and only need to add an argument and a single line of code in every place that needs it.

That being said, I feel like your structure could use a bit of redesign and moving the authentication to a different place to avoid breaking good code practices.